# React: update state with props change - handleChange and getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm trying to make some component which data output depends on some external API.

So I have this snippet:

```
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            somethingFromAPI: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        /* 
            something on axios.get() which updates this.state.somethingFromAPI 
            which normally can have some time delay till executed
        */
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Child value={this.state.somethingFromAPI} />
        )
    }
}

class Child extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            value: this.props.value || ''
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value
        })
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
        // if difference
        return {
            value: props.value
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
            </div>
        )
    }

}


ReactDOM.render(     
  <Parent />
  document.getElementById('app')        
);
```

Seems like this works fine, initializing component, and getting API data, after that, input value seems to be updated, which is what I expect.

Problem that hurts me a lot is if I type something inside input, that will call handleChange, but will also trigger this getDerivedStateFromProps and will replace newer inputed value with that "old" from API.

Is this good way of doing this, maybe I made mistake at start with understanding of how it should be done? Guide me in right direction.

I'm yet pretty new to React.

Generally, need to make form which I can use for new input, or updating existing data (like some posts, etc.), so I can load API data.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider using `shouldComponentUpdate` instead if using `getDerivedStateFromProps`

something like this may solve your problem:

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    const { value: nextPropsValue } = nextProps;
    const { value: propsValue } = this.props;

    const { value } = this.state;

    if (nextPropsValue !== propsValue && nextPropsValue !== value) {
      this.setState({
        value: nextPropsValue
      });
    }

    return value !== nextState.value;
  }
```

**Update the answer adding comparison  with current props value**

Answer (score 0):

I think using `getDerivedStateFromProps` here may be unnecessary.  If you want to prevent a render in certain cases, consider using `shouldComponentUpdate` https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate.  But it sounds like you basically just need to use your input change handler to keep the state of the input, which you're already doing.

You should also check [this](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-controlled-component) article out on why someone shouldn't use `getDerivedStateFromProps`.  It's very informative.